# iPhone Programming - complex JSON Parsing - UITableView

Tags: iphone, json, parsing, for-loop, key-value

Hey guys :) I am quite new to stack overflow and iPhone programming. I am trying to parse a complex JSON to display some stuff in the UITableView.

**a part of the JSON structure -**

```
{"1":{"1":"Ent1","done":"No"},"2":{"1":"Ent2","done":"No"}}
```

I am able to parse through the main keys "1" and "2" and able to grab the values corresponding to the key "1" inside {"1":"Ent1","done":"No"}, {"1":"Ent2","done":"No"} store them into a dictionary/ a string with the following code :

```
for (NSString *key in dict)
{
    NSString *answer = [dict objectForKey:@"1"];
    NSLog(@"%@", answer);
}
```

The result is Ent1 and Ent2 because the code iterates over the for loop and checks for the objects with key "1".

**The problem is this** - I want to store both the values(Ent1 and Ent2) into an array.

I use the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: answer, nil];
```

but it just takes the last index in the dictionary which is Ent2.

**Could you please tell me how could I add both the values for key 1 into an array?**

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *key in dict) 
{ 
    NSString *answer = [dict objectForKey:key];
    [array addObject:answer];
}
```

Comment: NSString *answer = ... <- missing the asterisk

Comment: @Jamapag Now if I NSLog this array inside the for loop, the array gives me 2 values - Ent1, Ent2

but when I try to NSLog it outside the scope it would just give me the last index value which is Ent2. Thus, if I use this array to be displayed in my tableview it just displays one value. 

Is there any work around that?

Thanks a lot guys, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

To add to jamapag's answer, you can also use JSON libraries in objective C which do all the work for you like [SBJSON](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) or [YAJL](http://gabriel.github.com/yajl-objc/index.html), or even as part of the more recent versions of the mac/iOS SDKs, [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I use JSONKit for json on ios.